# python inspect if caller function is a generator from

Tags: python, generator, inspect

I would like to retrieve information from within function's decorator about the caller function. Namely, I want to know if the caller function is a generator. Was trying with inspection of the outer stack frame but I could not find the way to do it

```
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        inspect.isgeneratorfunction(func) ### THIS WORKS 
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        ### HERE THE MAGIC

    return wrapper
```

Is it possible? Or is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Why would you need to know about what's calling you?

Comment: In few words: I am trying to change the behaviour of the decorator depending how the function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
generator = bool(frame.f_code.co_flags&32)
```

It looks from some small testing like at least in my version of python3, generators set flag 32 in the decimal code frame.
You'd want to check and see how portable that is, but probably reasonably portable at least on cpython.

Comment: Wow thanks! that is what I was looking for. But I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this eventually  using isgeneratorfunction cause this flag thing looks quite cryptic

Comment: No. isgeneratorfunction requires a function.  You can with a fair bit of work construct a function from a code block, but that's actually kind of tricky to get right and I think the flag, while obscure, is a better choice than that